# Showing rectangle is open

Tags: general-topology

i'm having some troubles following an example, showing that an open rectangle is an open set.

Can i write the steps down, and say where i don't understand? I have a set here
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJeVb.jpg)
The example looks at $R_1$ and proofs it's an open set. $R_1$ is given by:
$$ R_1 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 1 < x < 2, 1 < y < 3 \}$$

Then we define $P = (a,b) \in R_1 $ and note that
$$ a-1, \quad 2-a, \quad b-1, \quad 3-b $$ they are all postive and Let r be the smallest of them.
**I'm not sure why we are looking at these 4 identites. What's special abou them? I see they are from the defination of the space $R_1 $ but that's it...**

Now we claim any (x,y) is in the ball with any point P: $(x,y) \in B_r(P)$ Wich means:
$$ (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 < r^2$$
**I guess this part is legal becaus we have a ball? This is just the equation for the sphere**

Because of that earlier step this is also equivalent:
$$ |x-a| < r, \quad |y-b| < r $$
**Why is that true?**

With that an with
$$ r \leq a-1, \quad r \leq 2-a, \quad r \leq b-1, \quad r \leq 3-b $$
we can conclude that
$$ 1<x<2, \quad 1<y<3. $$
So $(x,y) \in R_1$

So as you can see i'm a bit confused about some of the steps.. I understand the main goal, how an open set is defined.. But i'm just not sure about these 3 steps and would love your input

Comment: If you have a point $(a,b) \in R_1$, then the 4 identities that confuses you are the distance of $(a,b)$ from every sides of the rectangles. By taking $r$ to be the minimum of these distances, you know that the ball of radius $r$ centered at $(a,b)$ is in $R_1$ since it the radius is smaller than the minimal distance from the sides. I hope this helps

Comment: There are several equivalent ways to define *open sets* in a topology.  It helps to say which one you are using.  In one approach a product of two open intervals (aka an open rectangle) is by definition a basic open set in the product topology.

Comment: I didn't know that. I'll keep that in mind. @hardmath

Comment: Oh i see @MaximeScott thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a point $(a,b) \in R_1$, then the 4 identities that confuses you are the distance of $(a,b)$ from every sides of the rectangles. By taking $r$ to be the minimum of these distances, you know that the ball of radius $r$ centered at $(a,b)$ is in $R_1$ since it the radius is smaller than the minimal distance from the sides.

To answer the second part of your question, let $(x,y)$ be a point in your ball $B_r(a,b).$ Then, since $r$ is the radius of the ball, you get that 
$$ r > \sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2} \geq \sqrt{(x-a)^2} \geq \vert x-a \vert $$
And you get a similar inequality for $\vert y-b \vert$. The last step simply uses the fact that $r$ is the minimum of the $4$ identities and therefore that $(x,y)$ is in $R_1$.

I hope this helps

Comment: This helped me a ton. Thank you or explaining that in detail to me.